# Get the script element of an inline script inside a non-inline script method

Tags: javascript

I have an inline script, say in `inline.html` and a library `library.js` whicht is not inline.

Inside the inline script I invoke `library.method()` and inside this method, I need to know, from which inline script the method was invoked.

```
library.method = function() {

    document.currentScript;

};
```

gives of course the library's script element.

But I need the script element of the invoking script: `document.invokingScript` for example. (I know, this does not exists).

Is ther something, I can do?

I don't want to do `library.method(document.currentScript)` in the inline script, for readability reasons.

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that you will call `library.method` only from inside a function, and that this wrapper function will have different name in each of your inline scripts - then you can use the following snippet (taken from https://gist.github.com/irisli/716b6dacd3f151ce2b7e)

```
var stackTrace = (new Error()).stack; // Only tested in latest FF and Chrome
var callerName = stackTrace.replace(/^Error\s+/, ''); // Sanitize Chrome
callerName = callerName.split("\n")[1]; // 1st item is this, 2nd item is caller
callerName = callerName.replace(/^\s+at Object./, ''); // Sanitize Chrome
callerName = callerName.replace(/ \(.+\)$/, ''); // Sanitize Chrome
callerName = callerName.replace(/\@.+/, ''); // Sanitize Firefox
```